# How to insert key and value to map that is inside another map in cpp?

Tags: c++, insert, mapping, iteration

I have this map :

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string> > objects;
```

As far as I know, when I write `objects[key]` it will replace the value of the key already exists, but here I want it to add to the second map if the pair doesn't exist.

```
Example:

    Current MAP :("key1",map(<"key_a","value_a">,<"key_c","value_d">))

input:
 "key1", "key_e","value_f" 
relsult:
("key1",map(<"key_a","value_a">,<"key_c","value_d">,<"key_e","value_f">))

input :
"key1", "key_e","value_g" 
(replace the value from "value_f" to "value_g")
result:
("key1",map(<"key_a","value_a">,<"key_c","value_d">,<"key_e","value_g">))

and if I get "key2" -> it will insert new key with empty map
```

can I do this :

```
objects[key].insert(std::make_pair(key2,value2))
```

it didn't work for some reason

can you please advise?

Comment: What did not work? What was the error/problem?

Comment: there's no "second" map, each key of your std::map<....> is related to a map, you have x "second" maps...

Comment: The code you've posted should do as you describe. Please give an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing how it didn't work (including exactly what you did, the expected result, and the observed result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I know, when I write `objects[key]` it will replace the value of the key already exists, but here I want it to add to the second map if the pair doesn't exist.

That's wrong: if you write `objects[key]` is doesn't replace anything, ever; rather:

- If `objects` doesn't already contain `key`, it inserts a new pair in the map with that key and for the value it uses a default constructed (in this case empty) `std::map<std::string, std::string>`.  It then returns a reference to the value.
- If `objects` does contain `key`, it returns a reference to the existing value (the "inner" map) without changing or replacing anything.

> can I do this: `objects[key].insert(std::make_pair(key2,value2))`

You could, but if `[key][key2]` already existing that wouldn't update the value to be `value2`, which I assume is what you want and why you say *"it didn't work"*.

All you have to do is:

```
objects[key][key2] = value2;
```

Because `objects[key]` never replaces an existing `map`, but default-constructs one if `key`'s missing, then `key2` either finds the existing entry in the "inner" map that needs updating *or creates it*, this all hangs together (if I've understood your requirement correctly).

Comment: just to be sure - > insert doesn't update the value, but using objects[key][key2] does it ? and also the second option will insert unexisting key2 ?

Comment: @user1386966 yes on all counts

Answer (score 0):

maybe you mean something like this?
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/count/

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string> > objects;
if (objects.count("your_key") > 0)
{   // insert a key ("another_key") into map
    objects["your_key"]["another_key"] = "some value";
} else
{   // create the new map for the key
    objects["your_key"] = std::map<std::string, std::string>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `insert`. Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main() 
{
    std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>> objects;

    objects["key1"] = { { "key_a", "value_a" }, { "key_c", "value_d" } };

    objects["key1"].insert( { "key_e", "value_f" } ); 

    for ( const auto &p1 : objects )
    {
        std::cout << "\"" << p1.first << "\": ";
        for ( const auto &p2 : p1.second )
        {
            std::cout << "{ \"" << p2.first 
                      << "\", \"" << p2.second
                      << "\" }" << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    objects["key1"]["key_e"] = "value_g"; 

    for ( const auto &p1 : objects )
    {
        std::cout << "\"" << p1.first << "\": ";
        for ( const auto &p2 : p1.second )
        {
            std::cout << "{ \"" << p2.first 
                      << "\", \"" << p2.second
                      << "\" }" << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"key1": { "key_a", "value_a" } { "key_c", "value_d" } { "key_e", "value_f" } 
"key1": { "key_a", "value_a" } { "key_c", "value_d" } { "key_e", "value_g" }
```